# How to substitute value in an array based on matched values in a dictionary?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift3

I have an String array such as:

```
var depatureDay: [String] = ["2", "4", "1", "5"]
```

and I have a dictionary

```
var dayDictionary: [String: String] = [
        "1": "Monday",
        "2": "Tuesday",
        "3": "Wednesday",
        "4": "Thursday",
        "5": "Friday",
        "6": "Saturday",
        "7": "Sunday"]
```

How do I iterate through the array to produce the array

```
["Tuesday", "Thursday", "Monday", "Friday"]
```

Comment: is this homework? lol, Why not loop through the departure array, taking each of the values, and using it as the "key" for the dictionary, to extract the day names which you will put in a new array.

Comment: The loop I tried didn't generate the outcome. Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @ruffdrum Don't you think it just single line code `let resultArray = depatureDay.flatMap { dayDictionary[$0] }`

Comment: I agree that one line of code is better. Any other advantage one way or the other?

Comment: @ruffdrum No need to check for nil `flatMap` will automatically ignored the nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seriously looks like homework....

```
var depatureDay: [String] = ["2", "4", "1", "5"]


var dayDictionary: [String: String] = [
    "1": "Monday",
    "2": "Tuesday",
    "3": "Wednesday",
    "4": "Thursday",
    "5": "Friday",
    "6": "Saturday",
    "7": "Sunday"]


var resultArray = [String]()

for dayKey in depatureDay {

    guard let foundDate = dayDictionary[dayKey] else {
        continue
    }

    resultArray.append(foundDate)
}

print(resultArray)
```

Comment: Perfect. It was part of a larger problem and I just tried to break it down to be as simple as possible. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in Swift 5.0:

```
let result = dayDictionary.filter{ depatureDay.contains($0.key) }.values

print(result)  //"["Thursday","Friday","Tuesday","Monday"]"
```